# Does subdifferential function with non-convex dom exist?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1499059/644032) question it was proved that, if $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\partial f(x)\neq \emptyset$ for all $x \in X$, then $f$ is convex.

But in the proof we used the fact, that $x = \lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda) x_2$ exists for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$, that means, set $X$ is also convex.

So my question: let's say that $X$ is **not convex**, $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\partial f(x)\neq \emptyset$ for all $x \in X$. Does function $f$ exist? Can you give an example of such a function?

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Did you try to, for example, construct a counterexample?

Comment: I think that, if I take f(x) = sin(x) with dom f = [pi, x0) ∪ (x0, 2pi], than dom f will not be convex, but function will still be subdifferential with subgradient cos(x). Am I wrong?